# How to Override a class in Sencha Touch

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

Could anyone let me know in simple steps that how how can I override a core component in Sencha code classes using the sencha architect 3 ?

I am struggling and trying to override the class as shown in this [post](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?273492-Back-button-broke-in-navigationview-Sencha-Touch-2.3-Android-4.3&p=1009111&viewfull=1#post1009111).

to get the default navigation back buttons to work with the sencha touch.

Could anyone please help me out ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean you want to override a core component like button?  Basically, every time you drag a button on to your canvas, you are creating an override of button. That is to say, if I take a button from my Sencha Architect toolbar for example and say "convert to component", the button code looks like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyButton', {
  extend: 'Ext.button.Button',
  alias: 'widget.mybutton',

  itemId: 'addButton',
  icon: 'resources/images/add.png',
  text: 'Add Record',

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

    me.callParent(arguments);
 }

});
```

You know have your own button that you can create either using the alias mybutton, or

```
 var myNewButton = Ext.create("MyApp.view.MyButton",{...});
```

You did ask specifically about override which means something different in architect.  I think you were thinking about what I have above but I'm not sure.  Override has to do with creating code that gets inserted into the above code but creating it as a second file with some inheritance tricks to merge it in.

Sorry for the long winded answer. Let me know if I missed the mark.